# Prevent my site from constant revisits

Tags: php, web

[My Path](http://xyz.in/node/58)

A couple of weeks back I deleted my application (code) from production and
just today I developed a new site and moved it to production.

In the site stats table, I noticed someone hitting the above path every 10 minutes, I know they are a hacker, now i want to remove my path from the automated machine database, because due to these automated machineperson hit my server bandwidth drastically increased.

How to protect site from automated machine?

Comment: How can you tell the automate machineperson apart from the rest of your site traffic?

Comment: Do not post links to paths where you don't want to have much traffic on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: They don't have to be a 'hacker'. It can be that someone linked to that page or something is trying to read content from your page.

Comment: Remove the link from the question. You may have post it for SEO issue. Read the 2nd comment. And do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check user ip's for spammer blacklist.use sites like stopforumspam.com's api. let me give you example code

```
function check_user($ip){
$var_url = "http://www.stopforumspam.com/api?f=json&ip=".$ip; 
$get = file_get_contents($var_url);
$me = json_decode($get,true);
$result = $me['ip']['appears'];
if($result==0){
$isspamer = 0;
}
else{$isspamer = 1;
}
return $isspamer;
}
```

and call the function like

```
if(check_user($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))die('you are a spammer access denied');
```

Comment: how ever we could not able to stop host hit. am i rite.

Comment: i didn't understand ur question

Comment: See, If someone enter my URL in the browser. then url hit goes to Apache or host, then entering into index.php, then only we are cal the above function. so how every hit is happening my site. due to these hit bandwidth get increased.

Comment: use htacess to restrict he users from viewing the unwanted directory's